# referencing to file in jquery

Tags: jquery, path

Well , I have a jquery function, results that I pass a filepath like a parameter, so when I run  the code, it seems doesnt find the file. do you have  any idea about what happend?
nevertheless, if I remove " ..\ " this part, and change the location of my file, it works well. I need that the file is located in the root site, 'cause is shared for various pages.

```
$.get("..\jobs.xml",{},function(xml){ 
    code inside funcition....
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See these example in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/):

```
$.get('ajax/test.html', function(data) {
  $('.result').html(data);
  alert('Load was performed.');
});

$.get("test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" } );
```

You're likely to encounter issue in production if you use relative paths. Why do you need them, anyway? What framework are you using?

Comment: Dreamweaver is your IDE, not your framework. Are you using PHP, Ruby, Python? At any rate, try not to use relative paths when calling a file   using $.get.

Comment: ok , Im using dreamweaver. Im using the function "Code Hint Tool/Url Browser to locate the pathfile, so , that one is wrote by itself. and this is the location throwed "../jobs.xml".
Im tried changing manually the pathfile '../jobs.xml','../../jobs.xml', '..\..\jobs.xml', etc. Im using this one cause the structure site is something like that:

root
      -jobs.xml
    js
      -readjobs.js
    css
      -style.css
    images
      -img.png
      -img2.png
    spanish
      -Jobs_es.html
    english
      -Jobs_en.html

Comment: Im trying to use the same "jobs.xml" file to save the information and use it to show it through the diferents html files. Im load the information using the jquery function. But just works if I put a copy inside each directory where the html files there. If I move to root site, so it seems doesnt work.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not using a server side language to get the info you need? For example, you could use $.ajax to request a given url in order to process the xml of your choosing and return the result to $.ajax function.

Comment: Yes, in fact the hosting doesn't support it, it's very poor, but well.  Im tested the site in iis and It's seems works. I hope when upload the site everything goes well.

Comment: Your hosting should support some server side language. PHP is almost mandatory. Ask about it because it's going to be necessary at some point unless your site is extremely simple.

Comment: thkns again Robert, I'll talk with the stackholders about it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the filesystem `..\` works for urls, so you can use `/jobs.xml` to reference the file at the root of your site.

Answer (score 0):

The "..\" path is used within filesystems, not URLs.

The best way to reference a variable file in a URL context would be as such:

```
../jobs.xml
```

Assuming you are at *http://yourdomain.com/test/example.html*, in your example you are pointing your query to the following:

```
http://yourdomain.com/test/..jobs.xml
```

When the example I have mentioned above will point to:

```
http://yourdomain.com/jobs.xml
```

Which I believe to be your intention.

Cheers!